# spring security authentication different profiles and permissions with hibernate and jsf

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, authentication, spring-security

i want to authenticate the users using spring security. i'm using hiebrnate and jsf.
the problem is in the different tutorials that i saw online there is just one role. but in my case i have a different database with permissions and profiles

Table User

- user id
- profile id
- login
- password

Table profile

- profile_id
- profile

Table action or permission

- action_id
- action
- profile_id

I am wondering if anyone knows how to implement this or knows some good tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to manage your user role, groups and permissions, you could see the [Spring Security documentation about schema](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-schema.html).
Here some snippets and details on the above link :

```
create table users(
      username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null primary key,
      password varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
      enabled boolean not null);

  create table authorities (
      username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
      authority varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
      constraint fk_authorities_users foreign key(username) references users(username));
      create unique index ix_auth_username on authorities (username,authority);
create table groups (
  id bigint generated by default as identity(start with 0) primary key,
  group_name varchar_ignorecase(50) not null);

create table group_authorities (
  group_id bigint not null,
  authority varchar(50) not null,
  constraint fk_group_authorities_group foreign key(group_id) references groups(id));

create table group_members (
  id bigint generated by default as identity(start with 0) primary key,
  username varchar(50) not null,
  group_id bigint not null,
  constraint fk_group_members_group foreign key(group_id) references groups(id));
```

Comment: this way, i have to use the schema in the documentation, but for me i want to use my own tables like i said earlier. is there a way to do that ?

Comment: You could see how they did and customize their example

Comment: but in this exemple, we only have the database schema not the implementation of an exemple on spring security